# Get tcpstream - wireshark vs tshark

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tshark

I'm trying to get the TCPStream from a capture, with size 24M. I can get it with wireshark but I need a command without interface to get this.

I started by trying the TShark in captures of less than 1M, and I was able to get tcpstream equal to wireshark in the same capture. In the capture with 24M, I can't. The TCPStream in wireshark is large and does not match what is given in TShark.

I can not understand what the problem is.

I'm using the following command: `tshark -r cap.pcapng -T fields -e data`

Any idea what the problem might be? Or what is it related to?

I'm available also for other solutions that can solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: [This one](https://serverfault.com/q/273066) might be interesting for you.

Comment: @PRVS How did you retrieve the TCPStream using Wireshark? When you say the output is different with Wireshark and tshark, what's the size difference? Are they entirely different or is there just one file with more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the most efficient way to do this but here it is.

Start with braking down your trace file in to multiple files, you can use `editcap` which is installed with Wireshark. Set the required parameters with `-c`. There could be a better way to this as well please do investigate(i did not)

Now you have multiple files which is not really nice to work with so you gonna have to create a batch file calling the tshark on each of these files. Open them apply parameters and write in to a new file(Again i told you it was not efficient)

`-r <infile> -R "here goes you parameters" -w <outfile>`

Still not there we have bunch of new files created but we better merge them into a single file for ease of use and to achieve a much smaller file than we start with. for this i suggest `mergecap -a`

`mergecap -a -w <outfile> <infile1> <infile2>......<infilen>`

Hope it helps